# Random Queue Simulator Customer Arrival Time

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue

I am having problem with code in generating random customer arrival. So the problem is suppose a store is expected to get 15 customers per hour. (that's .25 customer a min) So my logic here is 25% chance of getting a customer that minute of time.

Pseudocode:

```
generate a random float number 0.0 - 1.0 <= .25
     Add customer to queue
```

My first problem here is suppose a store expected 60 customer a hr so that's (1 customer a min) looking at my code above 0.0 - 1.0 will always be <= to 1 thus 60 customer WILL be added to queue 100% of time.

Second problem is suppose store expected 15 customer a hr there are chances they can get 1 or more customer at that min. How can i implement that on my code.

I have been looking into queue theory (Poisson, exponential distribution) for past 2 days but have not made a progress in finding my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem so just want to share it.

```
int ModelArrivalTimeGenerator::generateTime(double rate)
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937_64 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0, 1);

    return floor(-1/rate * log(distribution(mt)));
}
```

Suppose if you want to run simulation using arrival rate of 40 of whatever per hour. Pass in (40.00/60.00) as the parameter. I did some test and found out its pretty good at random arrival average.

This is a code you can use to check what is the avg if you run it n number of time.

```
double lamda = (15.00/60.00);   //(15customer/60min) gets you Arrival Rate per minute

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937_64 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0, 1);

    int CustomerArrivedAtTime = 0;

    int runThisManyTime = 20;
    int arrivalNum =0; 

    for(int i=0; i<runThisManyTime; i++)
    {
        while(CustomerArrivedAtTime < 60)
        {
            arrivalNum++;
            CustomerArrivedAtTime +=  floor(-1/lamda * log(distribution(mt)));
            cout << "Arrival#" << arrivalNum << " " << CustomerArrivedAtTime << "\n";
        }

        CustomerArrivedAtTime = 0;  // this is complete of first run 60 min is past in sim time so we reset for other run
    }

    cout << "\n\n AVG: " << arrivalNum/runThisManyTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve both problems by instead of checking per minute, check per less than a minute. If you just divide your chance by 60 and than check every second for example it would be way more accurate.

Getting a 100% accurate answer for such a problem is impossible so try looking for a good-enough solution.

Good luck